# Speeding up appending HTML elements into div via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am appending some elements in my `div` as a list view.
All the details of my items are stored in an array.
The appending is taking very less time when items are less around 50.
However when items size increase to 400 or more the it took lot of time in
appending my list.

How i can append div little faster or on fly to my div.

The structure is something like this.

```
<div id="main">
<div id="item"></div>
.....
.
.

.
.
<div id="item"></div>

</div>
```

This main div is as a different screen in my app.

Comment: you should use a paging concept if possible

Comment: I believe it might be to do with the browser repeatedly needing to do reflows on increasing numbers of elements. I suggest you try to add all the divs at once for large numbers to prevent this from occuring.

Comment: You'll need to show us your code but it boils down to performance-related mistakes - adding DOM elements one by one to the live dom, using jquery-style `each` over native loops, etc

Comment: also can you share your current code

Comment: you might want look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/17632397/1385627

Comment: @Hashem Qolami I am simply creating my items , and using append. In a for loop to append all items.

Comment: @clancer i am appending all div in a for loop, that why it take time

Comment: @SureshBora Check my comment at the bottom of Zword's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@arete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1148547/arete) has mentioned, [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) will increase the performance of appending elements into the DOM.

Using *DocumentFragments* is faster than repeated single DOM node injection and allows you to perform DOM node operations on new elements instead of mass-injection via `innerHTML`.

> The `DocumentFragment` interface represents a minimal document object
>   that has no parent. It is used as a light-weight version of [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document)
>   to store well-formed or potentially non-well-formed fragments of XML.
>   - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

We can create an empty *DocumentFragment*, using [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment) method, and append the created children by [`.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) JavaScript native method, as follows:

```javascript
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    limit = 400,
    element = 'div',
    clsName = 'item';

for (var i=0; i<limit; i++) {
    var box = document.createElement(element);
    box.className = clsName;
    // Append the child into the Fragment
    frag.appendChild(box);
}

// Finally, append the fragment into the real DOM (touch the DOM just once)
document.getElementById('main').appendChild(frag.cloneNode(true));
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/wQrEf/)**.

Here is a **[performance test](http://jsperf.com/out-of-dom-vs-documentfragment/3)** of using *DocumentFragments* on *jsPerf*

Also, I **[updated the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/xUA9L/11/)** demo which is provided by [@Zword](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648239/zword), you might want to consider.

Comment: Hashem +1 for well explained answer

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple plugin I made.Will surely be faster than appending items or divs one-by-one:

```
/*plugin code start*/
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.fastAppend = function(getHTML,limit){
var parent=$(this);
var str = "";
for(i=0;i<limit;i++)
{
    str = str + getHTML + "\n";
}
parent.append(str);
};}( jQuery ));
/*plugin code end*/

/*Call Plugin*/
$('#main').fastAppend('<div class = "item"></div>',400);
```

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xUA9L/9/)

---

***Check the execution time taken when***

*Case 1: When divs are appended one-by-one*

### [Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/xUA9L/7/)

*Case 2: When divs are concatenated in a string and appended altogether*

### [Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/xUA9L/8/)

> **Result :** ***Case 2***  is faster than ***Case1***

Comment: It would be faster if we use *Document Fragment* and JavaScript native `.appendChild()` method: http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/xUA9L/11/

Comment: @HashemQolami yes your code is a bit more faster but my code will solve the askers problem .Also it has lesser lines compared to yours and is also easy to understand.Your code is also good.Why dont you post it as answer?

Comment: Actually, arete has mentioned sort of using this approach in his answer. But about the more lines, It still seems simple to me :)

Comment: yes arete did post an answer where he mentioned the same approach but didnt post a working example. You can provide a working example in your answer and hence your answer will be more complete wrt the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Document fragments will give you a large increase in performance for the problem you're having. What you can do is create a document fragment for which all of your elements will be appended to and in turn append the document fragment to the element you plan on appending everything to.

The way to do this is to create a jquery object such as the following:

```
var foo = $("<div>");
foo.append($("<div id = "item"></div>"));
foo.append($("<div id = "item"></div>"));
...
foo.append($("<div id = "item"></div>"));
$("body").append(foo);
```

You can also alternatively use `.html()` to set the inner html of an element. See: [John Resig's DOM DocumentFragments article](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Building a string with all the content and then using `container.innerHTML = str` is a low-tech and ugly approach, but may be is faster.

Comment: Is bound to be faster since DOM modification happens just once.

Answer (score 0):

Always use **caching** for this as appending an element in **DOM** slows the process. Better, collect markups in a string, then append all in DOM at once. E.g:

```
var _sEleList = ""
for (var k=0; k < _nElements; k++) {
    _sEleList += "<div id="+ m_sPrefix+ k + " class='w_cClass'>Content</div>";
};
$('#w_oHolder').append(_sEleList);
```